# Chronological order

Tags: python

I'm trying to identify whether a chronological order is followed or not using Python. As a source of data I have an Excel file of requests.

But with the whole file it did not worked, by shortening (just using a copy of few hundreds of lines) it gave result but just the whole file duplicates (I think since the double loop, I think) without respecting any rules imposed in the IF.

Here is what I've tried to write:

```
while i < len(dateReq):
    l = 1
    while l < len(dateReq):
        if dateReq[i] < dateReq[l] and datePick[i] > datePick[l] and VAT[i] == VAT[l]:
            region.append(reg[l])
            province.append(prov[l])
            Name.append(nm[l])
            nvat.append(VAT[l])
        l += 1
    i += 1
```

I know there are some horrors, but I am just started

Comment: Side note: Avoid calling your variables `i` and `l` for reasons of keeping the sanity of whoever reads the code. The letters are too similar. (Unless you're doing it on purpose, then I recommend using an uppercase `I` and a lowercase `l`.)

Comment: Could you please add your error message? Are `datePick`, `dateRew`, `VAT`, `reg`, `prov` and `nm` all of the same length? I guess you are getting an index out of range error somewhere.

Comment: @Tomalak Sorry, you're right.

Comment: @mosc9575 The fact is that there are no errors, simply won't compile or find an end with the complete file excel. Meanwhile if I use a shortened version of 198 lines, it gave me as result 968 lines completely disregard the conditions I put in the if. Regarding the lists are all the same length.